# How to know which hash is is used

Tags: sql, encryption

I have a user table, each user has a password, and a password salt.

I want to reset every user password using a sql script, but I need to know which hash is used for password, here is an example:

```
pass : $2y$10$WjgvLQbIyx4Oab69b2vEKuOPafgWC2yzWD7JqYvC6dgvjW2iuNi/m
password salt: AF7
```

Comment: Why not inspect the code that generated the hashes in the first place?

Comment: Why not inspect the code that verifies the password?

Comment: actually, the client didn't give me ssh access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if the hashed password was generated with the PHP function [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php).

The `$2y$10$` at the beginning seems to indicate that the default algorithm was used (second parameter):

```
password_hash(password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

I hope you didn't use "AF7" as a salt for all passwords. That would completely defeat its purpose. It's the same as using no salt at all.

When setting new passwords, it's not relevant what hashing function was originally used. Instead, it's important what's used to verify the password. I assume that PHP's password_verify function is used. So you can easily use a different algorithm and a random salt. It's all encoded in the string that's stored in the database and `password_verify` will be able to handle it.

Comment: Why do you assume that is was done with PHP specifically? Afaik bcrypt hashes are the same regardless of the language/platform used.

Comment: @1615903: Yes, you're right, the dollar prefixes is part of the bcrypt standard. So it could have been any bcrypt implementation.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a hash generated by a method such as password_hash, bcrypt or a similar method.

Hashes are not encryption, they one-way functions designed not to be reversible, information is lost, by design, in the hashing function.

Comment: yes thanks you, i don't actually want to reverse the hash and get the password, i just want to know wich hash is used to generate new password for every user.